Is there a vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $\omega (X,\cdot )=df$?
Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$. Is there a vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $\omega (X,\cdot )=df$? where $d$ denotes the exterior derivative.
By $\omega (X,\cdot )$ I mean a one form field $M\to \bigcup_{p\in M}T^*_p M$ by $p\mapsto \omega_p (X_p ,\cdot):T_pM\to \mathbb{R}$.

Of course. A symplectic form is non-degenerate, so you can ‘invert it’ to get $X:=\omega^{\sharp}(df)$ (or more precisely $\omega^{\sharp}\circ df$). Here, $\omega^{\sharp}:T^*M\to TM$ is the musical isomorphism (google this) which is the inverse of $\omega^{\flat}:TM\to T^*M$, $v_p\mapsto \omega_p(v_p,\cdot)$.

This answer is a duplicate.

@peek-a-boo I appreiate your nice answer.

@peek-a-boo Sorry, I know that $TM=\bigcup_{p\in M}T_pM$ and since  $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$, then $df\in \Omega^1 (M)$, i.e., $df:M\to T^M=\bigcup_{p\in M}T^_pM$. so what does $df\in T^*M$ mean here?

@peek-a-boo In the definition of musical isomorphisms, do $TM$ and $T^*M$ mean $\chi (M)$ (the space of all vector fields) and $\Omega^1 (M)$ (the space of all 1-form fields)?

when did I write $df\in T^*M$? And no $TM,T^*M$ mean the tangent and cotangent bundles respectively, as is the standard notation.

@peek-a-boo You have defined $X=\omega^{\sharp}(df)$ and said $\omega^{\sharp}:T^*M\to TM$. So you meant $df\in T^*M$.

Well, in your post you also used the abridged notation $\omega(X,\cdot)$; besides, I did say “or more precisely $\omega^{\sharp}\circ df$”. Anyway you need to get comfortable going back and forth from: bundle morphisms between vector bundles, sections of the Hom bundle, and $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear maps between the spaces of sections.

@peek-a-boo You are right. I will study them precisely. Thank you very much four your help and guidance.
